# Send pageable object and search params to Spring Boot endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

I have this endpoint which I want to use to get data as pages:

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/task", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> processTask(@Valid TaskSearchParams params, Pageable pageable)
    {
        .....    
        return new ResponseEntity<>(....., HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Search Prams DTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class TaskSearchParams {

    private String title;
    private String status;
}
```

What payload for `TaskSearchParams` and `Pageable` I need to send? I tried:

```
{
    "size": 1,
    "pageNumber": 1,
    "offset": 1,
    "sort": "DESC"
}
```

But I'm not sure how I need to include `TaskSearchParams`.

Comment: You want to send TaskSearchParams as request body or query param? for pageable, you should send request like /task?page=0&size=10&sort=title,desc

Comment: I want to send both as DTO

Comment: ok, I'm wrong. these params should be path variables I think.

Comment: @SridharPatnaik is right.

Comment: I send from Angular SPA params. Looks like Spring is properly parsing them in the same way. Do you think that I need to do some improvements into the code that I have listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are path variables, you should enclose them in curly braces and annotate variable with @PathVariable

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/task/{title}/{status}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> processTask(@Valid @PathVariable String title, @PathVariable String status, Pageable pageable)
    {
        .....    
        return new ResponseEntity<>(....., HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: the problem is that there are too many variables. Looks like I will use DTOs.

Comment: If you want to use DTO, you better use POST call instead of GET and receive the data as request body using @RequestBody annotation